# C - error when allocating dynamic memory for linked list node

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to write a code that reads a text file to a linked list and stores in memory. I don't know why there are errors on `malloc` functions I use it in my code.

This is the pre-given header file that need to keep as is:

```
#ifndef ADDRESSBOOK_LIST_H
#define ADDRESSBOOK_LIST_H

#define NULL_SPACE 1

#define NAME_LENGTH (20 + NULL_SPACE)
#define TELEPHONE_LENGTH (10 + NULL_SPACE)

typedef struct telephoneBookNode
{
    int id;
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    char telephone[TELEPHONE_LENGTH];
    struct telephoneBookNode * previousNode;
    struct telephoneBookNode * nextNode;
} TelephoneBookNode;

typedef struct telephoneBookList
{
    TelephoneBookNode * head;
    TelephoneBookNode * tail;
    TelephoneBookNode * current;
    unsigned size;
} TelephoneBookList;
```

This is the code I write to load txt file into memory:

The `entry` has a format `ID, Name, Number` like `123, Alice, 0123456789`

```
#include "addressbook_list.h"
TelephoneBookList * createTelephoneBookList(char entry[])
{
    TelephoneBookList* aList = NULL;
    TelephoneBookNode* aNode = createTelephoneBookNode();
    char *tokens;

    tokens = strtok(entry, ", ");
    aNode->id = tokens;

    tokens = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    aNode->name = tokens; //Error: array type char[21] is not assignable

    tokens = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    aNode->telephone = tokens; //Error; array type char[11] is not assignable

    aNode->nextNode = aList->head;
    aList->head = aNode;

    if (aList == NULL)
    {
        aNode->nextNode = NULL;
        aNode->previousNode = NULL;

        aList->current = aNode;
        aList->head = aNode;
        aList->tail = aNode;
    }
    else
    {
        aList->tail->nextNode = aNode;
        aNode->nextNode = NULL;

        aList->tail = aList->tail->nextNode;
    }

    return aList;
}
```

This is the function to create nodes, I got error:

> incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char*', dereferenced with *

```
TelephoneBookNode * createTelephoneBookNode()
{
    TelephoneBookNode* aNode;

    aNode = (TelephoneBookNode*) malloc(sizeof aNode);

    aNode->id = (int) malloc(sizeof aNode->id);
    aNode->name = (char*) malloc(sizeof aNode->name);
    aNode->telephone = (char*) malloc(sizeof aNode->telephone);

    return aNode;
}
```

Please someone can explain me a bit on the error. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note: They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Isn't aNode->id an integer?  How can one assign heap memory to an integer?

Comment: ``aNode->id = (int) malloc(sizeof aNode->id);`` youhad a java class before, did you? You do not need to malloc integral values in the struct. An int is an integral value.

Comment: @AdrianM. By covering up the (not so pointless after all) warnings about pointer to integral conversion with that hideous `(int)` cast.

Comment: ``aNode = (TelephoneBookNode*) malloc(sizeof aNode);`` aNode is a pointer and its size is certainly not the same as that of a ``TelephoneBookNode``

Comment: @WhozCraig, ah, interesting!

Comment: @AdrianM. which brings me to a word of advice for the OP. Casting in C is rarely needed, and even then only in the hands of someone that *knows* the language, *seriously* understands what they're doing, and humble enough to admit fallibility. . For someone new to the language, it should be avoided like a plague of death. The requirements and language resources needed for dare-I-say-all learning-level projects shouldn't need it. If you find yourself writing code that doesn't compile without it, take it as a strong hint you're probably doing something very, *very* wrong.

Comment: There is also a bug in ``createTelephoneBookList`` regarding variable ``aList``.

Comment: Small quibble "An int is an *integer* value". An *integral* value would be "essential to completeness" or "very important and necessary"

Comment: @WhozCraig, something tells me you are not entirely a programmer by trade or education -- far too much witty linguistic flourish in your comment...

Comment: You're attempting to allocate memory for `aNode->name` and `aNode->telephone`, where you've already predefined their size in the struct (i.e. no allocation is necessary).  Also, `malloc(sizeof aNode)` will allocate 4 bytes on 32 bit systems, 8 on 64 bit; this is the size of a pointer.  What you want is `malloc(sizeof TelephoneBookNode)` or `malloc(sizeof *aNode)` <-- I've seen this notation, but I don't use it, I always use the struct name, even if it may be less safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
- You cannot assign to arrays, which will be converted to non-lvalue pointer when used as operand of `=` operator, in C.
- `TelephoneBookNode` has two pointers and some other members, but you allocated space for only one pointer. This will cause luck of space and out-of-range access in typical environment.
- Allocating a memory, converting it to some integer in implemention-defined manner and using it to initializing a menber looks weird.

Your `createTelephoneBookNode()` function should be like this:

```
TelephoneBookNode * createTelephoneBookNode()
{
    TelephoneBookNode* aNode;

    /* add dereference operator to get the size of what will be pointed by aNode */
    aNode = malloc(sizeof *aNode);

    /* do initialization of member if it is required */

    return aNode;
}
```

`strcpy()` function is available in `string.h` to copy strings, and `atoi()` function is available in `stdlib.h` to convert strings into integers. Using these, the part that is assigning data to members should be like this:

```
tokens = strtok(entry, ", ");
aNode->id = atoi(tokens);

tokens = strtok(NULL, ", ");
strcpy(aNode->name, tokens);

tokens = strtok(NULL, ", ");
strcpy(aNode->telephone, tokens);
```

Note that error checking is omitted here. Add them to make the program safer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to malloc for following:

```
aNode->id = (int) malloc(sizeof aNode->id);
aNode->name = (char*) malloc(sizeof aNode->name);
aNode->telephone = (char*) malloc(sizeof aNode->telephone);
```

As memory is already allocated when you declared them  .
You just need to allocate memory for link list node ,like:

```
TelephoneBookNode * createTelephoneBookNode()
{
    Telephonenter code here`eBookNode* aNode;

    aNode = (TelephoneBookNode*) malloc(sizeof aNode);

    return aNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- int id is an integer and not a pointer, so no need to malloc.
- Both are char arrays of fixed size, No need to malloc for it.
- Only for a node you can do a malloc and thats sufficient.